# Asymptotic estimation/order of a simple product

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $(a_n)\subset \mathbb{R}$ a nonnegative sequence such that $a_n \to 0$.

Let $(b_n)\subset \mathbb{N}$ a nonnegative sequence such that $b_n \to +\infty$.

I would like to estimate (have an equivalence) the following quantity as $n\to +\infty$ : $$\prod_{i=0}^{b_n-1}(a_n+2i) .$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the $2$ by $c$,
and modifying it a little
to make things easier,

$p_n
=\prod_{i=1}^{b_n}(a_i+ci)
=c^{b_n}b_n!\prod_{i=1}^{b_n}(1+a_i/(ci))
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\ln p_n
&=b_n\ln c+\ln b_n!+\sum_{i=1}^{b_n}\ln(1+a_i/(ci))\\
&\approx b_n\ln c+\ln b_n!+\sum_{i=1}^{b_n}(a_i/(ci)+a_i^2/(2c^2i^2)^2+o(1/i^3))\\
&\approx b_n\ln c+b_n(\ln b_n-1)+\frac12\ln b_n+\frac1{c}\sum_{i=1}^{b_n}(a_i/i)+D
\qquad\text{since the sums converge}\\
&\approx b_n(\ln b_n-1+\ln c)+\frac12\ln b_n+o(\ln b_n)+D
\qquad\text{since } a_i \to 0\\
\end{array}
$

If
$\sum_{i=1}^{b_n}(a_i/i)
$
converges
(for example,
if
$a_i
=1/\ln^2(i)
$),
then this simplifies to
$\ln p_m
\approx  b_n(\ln b_n-1+\ln c)+\frac12\ln b_n+D_1
$,
where $D_1$ is another constant.

Comment: Thank you, but actually, in the term $a_.$, the subscript is $n$, not $i$. Anyway, I used what you wrote and made an attempt of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the previous answer, I write down my attempt :

Let $p_n
=\prod_{i=0}^{b_n-1}(a_n+2i)
$, then
\begin{align*}
p_n &= a_n\prod_{i=1}^{b_n-1}(a_n+2i)
\\&=a_n^{b_n} 2^{b_n-1} (b_n-1)! \prod_{i=1}^{b_n-1} (1+\frac{a_n}{2i})
\end{align*} 
hence, \begin{align*}
\log p_n &= b_n\log a_n+ (b_n-1)\log 2 + \log( (b_n-1)!)+ \sum_{i=1}^{b_n-1} \log (1+\frac{a_n}{2i})
\\&=b_n\log a_n+ (b_n-1)\log 2 + \log( (b_n-1)!) + \sum_{i=1}^{b_n-1}  \frac{a_n}{2i} + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{a_n}{2i})^2 + \epsilon_{i,n}
\\&= b_n\log a_n+ (b_n-1)\log 2 + \log( (b_n-1)!) + \sum_{i=1}^{b_n-1}  \frac{a_n}{2i} +o(1)
\\&=b_n\log a_n+ (b_n-1)\log 2 + \log( (b_n-1)!)+  \frac{a_n}{2}(\log b_n +\gamma + O(1/b_n)) + o(1)
\\&=b_n\log a_n+ (b_n-1)\log 2 + \log( (b_n-1)!) +  \frac{a_n}{2}\log b_n +o(1).
\end{align*}
So that, $$p_n = \exp (b_n\log a_n+ (b_n-1)\log 2 + \log( (b_n-1)!) +  \frac{a_n}{2}\log b_n +o(1) ) .$$